# evitar editar o guardar valores de un input al usar inspeccionar elemento?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola tengo una consulta que no soy capaz de encontrar solución tengo un input sencillo

```
<input class="control__inputs" id="suma_total" type="number" name="" value="2.80" disabled="" readonly="readonly">
```

Estoy usando php y mysql para guardar el total en una bd. Para poner contexto la aplicaccion que estoy haciendo no hace mas que registrar y sumar ventas al dar click en guardar simplemente se guarda o en caso de ya existir la venta actualiza con el nuevo valor el total lo muestro en un input el problema es que si abro inspeccionar elemento y cambio el valor del input facilmente se guarda al presionar guardar. Creo que evitar la modificacion del html usando inspeccionar elemento es imposible, pero hay alguna manera de colocar restricciones usando php para evitar guardar los datos que se modifican al usar inspeccionar elemento?
El el campo value lo lleno con php desde mysql

```
 <input" id="suma_total" type="number" value="<?php echo $row['total_suma'];?>" disabled readonly="readonly">
```

Quedo atento a cualquier sugerencia gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es posible desactivarlo, hay scripts de JS que deshabilitan el click derecho o F12 pero aun así existen muchas formas de lograrlo, si lo que quieres es mantener un balance puedes limitar la cantidad, si es mayor a x cantidad usando algun if en php o bien, usar algun campo oculto y verificar si el valor del campo oculto es igual al campo que quieres proteger, aun asi cuando se trata de fronted poco se puede hacer.

En teoría si lo desactivas con disabled el valor no se enviara por POST así que aunque se modifique el fronted el valor no debería de cambiar en backend.

Comment: gracias por la recomendacion